# Is it possible to query a table using Django's ORM without creating a class for it in models?

Tags: django, django-orm

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I have a database where I know there is a table called `Customer`, but this is not present in the `models.py`. Therefore, I can't simply do the following:

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(age__gte=25)
```

Is it possible to write this query and get the data without creating a class for it in `models.py` and migrating the whole project?

Comment: You can make unmanaged models, this thus means that Django will not create/migrate the table itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a class, but you *don't* need to let the Django ORM manage it through migrations. You can do this by adding the meta option `managed = False` [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#managed)].

To save you time and headaches, Django offers a management command `inspectdb` [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)], which will output a class definition for you, including all fields found in the database.

`python manage.py inspectdb [table_name]`

Then you can use this, and set the meta option (I believe it defaults to `managed = False`, though). It will look something like this:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    age = models.IntegerField(...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    date_joined = models.DateField(...)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'someTableName'
```

Now you can import the class and run:

```py
customers = Customer.objects.filter(age__gte=25)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make models that are *not* managed. You do this by specifying the [**`managed = False`** option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#managed) in the `Meta` of your model. As is specified in the documentation:

> If `False`, **no database table creation or deletion operations** will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when `managed=False`. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal. (…)

You can thus create a model in your `models.py`:

```
# app/models.py

from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Customer'
```

Then you can make queries with the Django ORM, just like you would have done as if it was a managed model.